# Automatic picture resizing, zoom and positioning

Tags: adobe-premiere

i was wondering if there is a way in adobe premiere or another program to automatically lay pictures over another and resize them. I have multiple pictures with the same motive from roughly the same distance so about the same size in the picture with a different background. To make a video id like to lay all of them over another and have the foreground at the same position at the same size. Is this somehow possible or do i need o do it manually?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way I can think to do this would be to create a sequence that is the frame size you want the photos to be and then ensure that

"Preferences --> General --> Default Scale To Frame Size" is selected. Then every photo you lay into the sequence will scale to that same size.

You can also resize the images in photoshop as well. Hope that information helps.